# Regex needed in C# to determine if multiple words are within N words

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following problem that I think regex should be able to solve. I need to determine whether the following pattern is found in a string. The pattern begins with one of three words and must be followed, but not immediately, by two other words and the pattern must be found within a total length of N words.

As an example let the first word be 'severe', the last two words are 'aortic' and 'stenosis' and let N = 6. Sentence #1 should match because all three words are found within five words but #2 should not because all three words are found within ten words which is greater than N = 6.

1. There was severe to critical aortic stenosis.
2. He had a severe allergy when admitted but was diagnosed with aortic stenosis.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you just need the regular expression? or do you need C# code for regex as well?

Comment: just the regex is fine, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Regex monkey = new Regex(@".*[severe ][\b\w*\b ]{0,3}[aortic stenosis].*");
```

My Regex is a little rusty, but I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the word characters feature of regex in c#.  For example

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String example1 = "There was severe to critical aortic stenosis.";
        String example2 = "He had a severe allergy when admitted but was diagnosed with aortic stenosis.";
        // {m,n} words
        Regex reg = new Regex("severe (\\w* ){0,6}aortic stenosis");
        Console.WriteLine(reg.ToString());

        Match m1 = reg.Match(example1);
        Match m2 = reg.Match(example2);

        Console.WriteLine(m1.Success);
        Console.WriteLine(m2.Success);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```